# Internet Explorer crashes with specific input on a hidden textarea

Tags: html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

**NOTE: If you follow the steps below on IE11 (haven't tried other IE versions) it may crash your browser. So be prepared for that.**

Open up my sample at http://jsfiddle.net/b8JZq/2/

I have a simple setup with a `textarea` hidden by default (via css style) and a `button` that shows the `textarea`.

1. Click on the button to show the text area.
2. In the textarea, enter only new line characters.
3. Click outside the textarea.

This consistently causes my IE11 to crash. Works fine on Chrome, Safari, FF versions I have tried.

Entering any other text apart from new lines only does not cause the issue. Problem also does not happen if the textarea was visible to begin with. Is there a workaround to this?

Comment: Have you tried setting the textarea to readonly before hiding it?

Comment: Not able to replicate it here on IE11.

Comment: I can reproduce this in IE11 (version 11.0.9600.16659)

Answer (score 0):

Now this is a known bug for the IE team: http://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/808986/ie-11-entering-value-with-newline-in-textarea-crashes-browser